# Post request with System.Net.WebClient

Tags: c#, post, webclient

I believe the answer is simple but none of the code samples I've found worked...
Basically I'm trying to send a post request using System.Net.WebClient, with a string parameter; But the server gets the parameter as null.
It has to be written in dotnet 2, so I can't use HttpClient (which worked by the way).

client:

```
        using(var client = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var res = client.UploadString(_uri, "POST", "test");
                if (res != "test")
                    return false;
            }

            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                  Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
                  return false;
            }
```

service:

```
            public string Post([FromBody]string value)
            {
                return value;
            }
```

Comment: Try adding content type to your request: `client.Headers.Add("Content-Type","text/plain");`. Did it work?

Comment: It didn't work. I got an internal server error when using it

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this code, but try it out. You can add more headers, if it throws more errors it might require more specific headers.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
string yourURL = "http://example.com/example.php";
string PARM= "par1=value1&par=value2";
client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string result= client.UploadString(yourURL, PARM);

if(result != "test"){
return false
}
}
```

Comment: It didn't throw any errors, but the still got null parameter on the server.. Any ideas for other headers that might work?

Comment: Like do you mean that the response you're getting is literally "null"?

Comment: Yes. When debugging the Post([FromBody]string value) function, value parameter is null

Comment: Try adding: `client.Headers.Add("Content-Type","text/html");`

Comment: I still get the same result